# Modal Dialog Window submit Form

Tags: css, asp-classic, window, modal-dialog

I have a form which is displayed in an CSS/JS modal window

```
<div id="mWindow1">
<div>
<% = FormHere %>
</div>
</div>
```

Form submits fine and my data is added to the database, after that form has been submitted, how do I display a confirmation message in the same modal window.

Thanks

John

Comment: you have to Show more code at least the JavaScript you open the modal window with. better you Show some classic asp code also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578944/modal-forms-array-is-the-possible

Given up on that for now, just need to be able to use a modal window to handle and form and post submission